# Access denied when attempting login to servers with Domain Users via RDP

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, remote-desktop

I have a VM server, with VSphere, I have 2 windows server 2003 VMs:

A server holds the DNS, DC and AD roles.
IIS holding a web platform that allows Domain Admins to create new Domain Users (which are also added to the Remote Desktop Users group of the DC)
And also 1 windows 7 VM. All these VMs are computers on the same domain (which is sitting on the DC VM).

I access all those VMs through Remote Desktop, when I try to login with a Domain user which is not a Domain Admin to any VM (beside the DC/AD VM) I get this error:

> "The requested session access is denied."

What should I do and how can I fix it?

Comment: Add the users to the Remote Desktop Users group of the virtual machines you want them to log onto.

Comment: so when a user is being created I need to add it to all Remote Desktop Users groups in all the VMs? what if I'll add computers in the future? I'll need to add all the users manually to the group?

Comment: System administration requires effort. There are a number of ways to accomplish this, these are just a few of those possible ways: 1. You can use Group Policy to add the domain Users group to the local Remote Desktop Users group. 2. You can manually add the local Users group to the local Remote Desktop Users group. - 3. You can manually add the domain Users group to the local Remote Desktop Users group.

Comment: currently the users are in the Remote Desktop Users Group on the DC/AD VM, I've added the Domain Users group to the local Remote Desktop Users group. the question is if I need to add them to the Remote Desktop Users group in each VM/Domain Computer?

Comment: If you want them to be able to log into each VM via RDP then they need to be in the local Remote Desktop Users group. However you decide to do that is up to you. Another method would be to modify which group is allowed to login to the virtual machines via RDP by selecting them on the Remote tab of the System Properties pages. If you add the local Users group or the domain Users group then they'll be able to log on. Note that this method simply adds the group(s) that you select to the Remote Desktop Users local group, so it's doing the same thing it's just using a different method.

Comment: Tnx I guess I'll just add all the users I want to allow to RDP into the DC local Remote Desktop Users group and then just add this group to all VMs and Domain Computers